# JQuery working on .html but not on .php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I really thought at first that my code is not working.. but then i tried to create a very simple click event in a clean page and my jquery works on .html but when i open the .php on my XAMPP server it does nothing when it's clicked but it alerts the first one.

index.php

```
<html>

<head>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<?php include "includes/widgets/login.php"; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

login.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Something");
    t = clicked();
    $('#login').click(function() {
        alert("Login Alert!");
    });
    function clicked() {
        alert("I was clicked!");
    }
});
</script>

<input type="button" value="Login" id="login" onclick="clicked()">
```

Comment: Paste your `login.php` code also

Comment: edited it now. sorry for the delay.

Comment: @Siege21x  it seems you added php page into html page? if it is it will not wotk

Comment: the onclick event is also not working but when i declared it on a variable it is working

Comment: @AlivetoDie, But it alert the message, atleast alert will work. siege21x, please check the browser console ( in developer tools ) for any error.

Comment: Why is the file php? Also, if it had php, it would not be executed. Typically, the $(document).ready needs to be in the initial html loaded. If you want this to work, you have to include external JS using the tag like you did for the jQuery.

Comment: @AlivetoDie i translated it into 1 web when i tried it on html.

Thanks for the response peopl!

Comment: Console says.. "index.php:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: clicked is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.php:22)"

Answer (score 2):

place the function clicked(); outside from the document.ready();

Comment: Thank you for your response brother! But it seems to be the problem is with my computer :D i tried to send a message at console when i click the button and it reaches the log but it just doesnt want to show the message box. Thank you very much for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

Change login code to following and it will work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Something");

    t = clicked();
    $('#login').click(function() {
        alert("Login Alert!");
    });
});
function clicked() {
    alert("I was clicked!");
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="Login" id="login" onclick="clicked()">
```

***Uncaught ReferenceError: clicked is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.php:22)***

This problem will also solved. I don't know properly but i thought that browser can't find function inside jquery.

JQuery create function when DOM is ready.But Control onclick property was read by browser while creating a page but they can't find the function becuse it was not ready yet

So I think procedure may be like :

1) Browser read the page and find the function.

2) JQuery ready event will fire.

Comment: Thank you for your response brother! But it seems to be the problem is with my computer :D i tried to send a message at console when i click the button and it reaches the log but it just doesnt want to show the message box. Thank you very much for the effort!

Comment: If you would like then i can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Place your function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("Something");
t = clicked();
$('#login').click(function() {
    alert("Login Alert!");
});

});
 function clicked() {
    alert("I was clicked!");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response brother! But it seems to be the problem is with my computer :D i tried to send a message at console when i click the button and it reaches the log but it just doesnt want to show the message box. Thank you very much for the effort!